# rank-sum test vs. anova

Tags: regression, anova, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a set of data looks like this:

| hwid | freq | code | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 5150 | 764 | 24 |
| 101 | 5170 | 768 | 24 |
| 101 | 5190 | 764 | 24 |
| 102 | 5150 | 752 | 24 |
| 102 | 5170 | 760 | 24 |
| ... | ... | ... | 24 |

The data represents "power level" (decibel) of the radio transmitter hardware, where   `hwid` column identifies the hardware, `freq` is the frequency of transmission in MHz, and `code` represent the "instruction" for a specific hardware to emit the desired dB level, which is the `output` column.

We have to test 24 frequency points for every hardware unit, which is very time consuming.  The idea now is trying to find out "patterns" via statistical methods so that we can just test a few frequency points and guess the code for all 24 points for a specific unit.  For example, at 5190MHz, a unit's code is 10% above average, can we assume that for all frequency points that unit is 10% above average?  Apparently that is too simplified and virtually can't be true.  But what if we can also found out the relationship between error and frequency and use it as function to calculate codes?

---

The above is background of my question (to avoid [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

For now, what I am doing is trying to find out: **whether the difference in code has some relationship with frequency, or they are purely random**?

I extract the code for every frequency point into multiple series, so there are 24 series. Then I try to use rank-sum test for every two of them and found that some frequencies are different and some are not...   i.e. I try to "cluster" the frequency points into groups so that I can reduce the actual tests required.

I have two questions for now:

1. Of course I am just doing some research trying to get something out of raw data.  If you have any suggestion for the original problem, I am very appreciated to hear.
2. Just for the sake of my little test, I learned that rank-sum test are only for **two** data series, while for more than 2, we should use "ANOVA".  Is that true?  If so, the null-hypothesis for (one-way) ANOVA is that the mean of all samples are same, or, they come from the same big population.   What else can ANOVA do? Can it tell me the outlier, for example: series a,b,c are same while series d differs from them, etc.

Comment: Can you show graphs of the time series that you want to cluster? It would help to have a visual representation of the process(es) you'd like to model. Also, plotting the data is often a great place to start the analysis.

Comment: As a matter of fact, my knowledge on statistics is not enough to determine which is the best method/model to use.  So, clustering might not be the way to go.  For the problem itself, I guess "regression" might be the direction to go.  But, as a learning process, I am also interested in ANOVA (question 2), even if it does not fit the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on domain knowledge, which only you can answer, and if you can't then you probably shouldn't assume, maybe try doing some research to see if anyone else already figured something out.

Assuming the proportions are the same across all devices and it's just the level that shifts between devices (one device 10% higher than another in all frequencies) then you can sample just a couple of frequencies from each device, learn the mean of each device, learn the proportions from all the data, and then apply these to predict all the frequencies for all the devices. If the situation is more complex than that (not just a level shift), you cannot get away with such an approach.

Clustering could potentially work, but you would first have to get complete data for all the frequencies for at least a couple of devices, so that you will be able to accurately cluster after that new partial measurements. But even this depends highly on the data.

Comment: Domain knowledge from the engineers show that this is probably caused by hardware design or manufacturing, i.e. we cannot assume, for example, errors is larger while frequency got higher etc... At the moment, there is no physical rule to rely on, only mathematics.

Comment: @xrfang Then I don't think this can be done. You might still try, and a lot of people do end up in this situation, but the results may be questionable. A simpler (but not quite correct) model might still be better than no model, if you do proceed with such a model I would recommend randomly sampling frequencies to be tested for each device.

Comment: So, I am asking 2 questions, the intention is to study some statistical techniques :-)

Comment: @xrfang As far as methods are concerned, I would start with a mixed linear model, where the devices are the random effects and the frequencies are the nested effects.